# Javascript - modify regexp constructor or add tokens

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse input against complex regexp's that have common elements.

I would like to make it like `"My text from 2014".match(/{date}/);`

Where date would be some another long regexp or some set of another tokens like

`Regexp.tokens.date = /{year}|{month}|{day}/` etc.

And then as it uses another tokens

```
Regexp.tokens.year = /** Some native regexp matching year number **/
```

I want all those `{tokens}` to be **(recursively)** parsed to native regexp before testing.

In other words - I want to add list of tokens and their meaning and then to be able to make regexp using them.

I was trying to modify constructor of RegExp but it dont make any change.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hacking around with existing stuff, you should always create your own *wrappers*.

Something like:

```
function MyRegex(src,flags) {
    for( var k in MyRegex.tokens) if( MyRegex.tokens.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        src = src.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+k+"\\}","g"),MyRegex.tokens[k]);
    }
    this.pattern = new RegExp(src,flags);
};
MyRegex.tokens = {
    "year": "your regex as string here",
    // ...
};
MyRegex.prototype.test = function(str) {
    return this.pattern.test(str);
};
// define more methods as needed
```

To use:

```
var regex = new MyRegex("{date}");
console.dir(regex.test("My text from 2014"));
```